# Determining Ambient room temperature from IC's die temperature

Tags: integrated-circuit, temperature

Nowadays many IC's have inbuilt temperature sensor which probably gives the die temperature. According to my knowledge this junction temperature is always on higher/lower side respective of cold & hot environment - it never gives room temperature.

Is there any method or technique available to find ambient room temperature from the available die temperature of ICs?

Comment: You'd have to account for the self-heating of the IC by accurately measuring its power consumption and the efficiency of the heatsink. It seems rather backwards; dedicated temperature measuring ICs are cheap enough.

Comment: Use a fan to blow across it to keep it close to local ambient.

Comment: It is possible to get an *estimate*, but as thermal resistance values junction to ambient vary with many things including PCB specifics, it would probably not be very close.